# Hangfire, как поставить все сервера на паузу?

Tags: c#, .net-core, hangfire

Какой механизм есть у Hangfire, чтобы поставить на паузу все сервера (или 1, который сам будет следить за тем, что ему пора встать на паузу)?

Например: у нас есть сервис, к которому обращаются 5 hangfire серверов (отправляют http запросы), но неожиданно сервис упал на N минут и уже нет смысла отправлять туда запросы какое-то время.

Как поставить сервера на паузу, чтобы они выждали, условно говоря, 2 минуты, а потом продолжили отправлять запросы?

Единственное, что нашел: `IBackgroundProcessingServer.SendStop`, но Resume или Unpause нет.

В том же Quartz.NET есть `scheduler.PauseAll()` и `scheduler.ResumeAll()`

UPD: Найдено решение для 1 сервера: через `JobStorage` и `GetMonitoringApi()` + `DeletedJobs(0, int.MaxValue)`, а затем добавить удаленные обратно, но решение не пойдет для 2+ серверов

Comment: [A way to pause/stop jobs from being processed](https://github.com/HangfireIO/Hangfire/issues/225), но там не особо чего есть. Разработчик советует просто пересоздать сервер: _"Simply dispose and recreate an instance of the BackgroundJobServer class"_. Плюс обсуждение - кто как выкручивался из ситуации.

Answer (score 0):

Можете попробовать

- Масштабирование обработчиков:

> Вы можете изменить количество рабочих    (worker'ов), которые
> Hangfire использует для обработки заданий,    динамически масштабируя
> их вверх и вниз. Приостановка обработки    заданий может быть
> реализована путем уменьшения количества рабочих до    нуля.

```
public void ScaleDownServer(JobStorage storage)
{
    var options = new BackgroundJobServerOptions
    {
        WorkerCount = 0
    };
    
    var server = new BackgroundJobServer(options, storage);
    server.SendStop();
    
    // Чтобы возобновить обработку, создайте сервер с нужным количеством рабочих
}
```

Comment: Выглядит, если честно, как костыль. Да и не понятно, зачем мне создавать обработчик и сразу же его останавливать?